In new job manager is asking me to bring up output. Large part of my time spent is trying to understand communication from team
I started a new job 2 months ago. I was hired because the team was behind with a certain type of work. I think my manager isn't very familiar with the job I do and the only metric he looks at is the number of cases I close per day in the ticket management system. He wants me to bring this number up. If I'm being honest one part of my job that takes a lot of time is that I have trouble understanding the instructions from my coworkers and communication with them seems to be very slow.
Roughly speaking I get my work from the tickets that are assigned to me. Other people on my team work on them before I do my part, and often times I find the notes they leave hard to understand. They contain a lot of short hand, acronyms and jargon. I was told that different people on the team fill out the tickets differently and write in the notes with different formats. They don't seem to value a streamline approach.
It's hard to give good examples, especially one that doesn't require knowledge of the system, but lots of instructions seem like they are missing information. For example often times people say "check x". I'm left wondering "check x for what, and what should I do if I see it?". I could ask and get an answer, but my current issue is my manager wants me to work faster and usually asking such questions evolves into a discussion rather than a short answer. One time I asked a coworker how to do something, he just replied with a screen shot with a couple sections highlighted. I find these types of answers rather lacking in details.
Should I mention any of this to my manager? If so, how should I phrase it? Management already knows that documentation is missing. The work I do is repetitive (I'm surprised it hasn't been automated) but there is a fair amount of variability in the time it takes me to close a ticket because some need more work. My manager says he knows this but I doubt he knows to what degree.

You say that the work is repetitive, and you are fairly new to it.  Are things gradually improving as you get more tickets and see the same sorts of problems over & over?

"They contain a lot of shorthand, acronyms, and jargon." - Have you informed your supervisor that using acronyms and jargon makes it difficult to do your job and asked for a list that defines those acronyms and jargon?  However, after two months, are you starting to understand the shorthand, acronyms, and jargon? I would find a screenshot with the specific section I should focus on extremely helpful. I would of course assume there was some context that you have not shared with us.

@Donald documentation is missing and it seems like people use different words differently. For example saying "add an account to..." and "map an account to..." I had understood to be two very different and distinct tasks. But someone used the words interchangeably which messed me up, so that's one example. "Have you informed your supervisor that using acronyms and jargon makes it difficult to do your job": I've brought up a couple examples and his response was "I don't know what that means either".

@ClanLatin - So, did you ask him to get you those answers? He wants you to work faster; tell him what is preventing that, and ask them what you need to accomplish his desires. When he complains about the speed at which you work at, remind him of those deal beakers, and continue to request those answers from them.

You have some options.
Like with most things though - you need to make your case in terms of what Management wants.
So let us start there - Management expects a certain number of tickets to be handled in a given day. For the sake of easy maths - let us say the number is 8 tickets per day (1 per hour).
Let us assume currently you are averaging around 4 per day, a ticket every 2 hours.
You believe a key factor in this is that the information you recieve on an escalation or ticket hand-over is confusing or insufficient and that the business does not have sufficient documentation.
I would suggest that trying to persuade your boss to allow you time to get the documentation up-to-standard when you are behind on your ticket closure stats is unlikely to get the greenlight in the first instance - but, we will get to that.
The first think I would do is take a sample of the next weeks worth of tickets and make some additional notes as to where time is being lost. For example, missing credentials, incorrect application name, lack of screenshots etc. Whatever it is that is the biggest time sink.
For example: at one company, a we had multiple isolated networks, but with similar server names in each one - so web1 was not very helpful as it could be web1 in network 10 or web1 in network 23 etc. And finding that information although not super difficult was annoying because the person who took the initial call would have had to find that info out anyway. So we made it a rule that any escalation had to include that info. Saved the T3 team a couple of minutes per ticket.
The lesson here is to identify what bits of information you need and what is the best way to standardize (within the realms of reason) that information so that when a ticket is passed to you, you have all the necessary information to work on it.
You then want to present both your suggestion and the estimated time savings, along with your data:

Boss, I have been looking at ways to achieve the targets that are set,
I have done some personal time tracking on my last weeks worth of
tickets. On average, I am having to spend around 10 minutes of time
chasing the following details which are often not included by the
previous tech (Server name, IP, Credential etc.) - I have come up with
a standard escalation template that if the other techs were to use and
fill in the appropriate information, then it could help us close
tickets 10 minutes quicker.

Key things to note here is not to make the template too onerous (focus on maybe 3-4 things max initially) - the point is not to fix all the problems in one go, but to do a mini Proof-of-Concept whereby you demonstrate to your boss you have understood and inefficiency within the business and have a proposed solution to fix it. All going well, your solution will be implemented, will generate the efficiency you desire and then you can go to the next phase:

Boss, I have noticed that for these top 10 problems that we get a lot
of, the documentation around them is pretty spotty, these problems
represent X number of hours. I feel if we were to document this into a
runbook, then it could help our T1 team resolve it themselves or it
would streamline the escalation process leading to a faster ticket
resolution.

Now that you have demonstrated your PoC works, you will have more buy-in from management to implement solutions that require a bit of time investment from the company (in terms of not doing tickets) but hopefully with a larger gain in terms of efficiency.
TL;DR - identify some small innefficiencies that you can fix with a small standard template, get it implemented, demonstrate an improvement - then talk about documenting the wider business

You have a short sighted crappy boss, but that is obvious.
People will tend to do what they are measured. That is a basic understanding of management.
Your manager (whole management team?) puts an arbitrary metric of closed tickets a higher priority than client satisfaction. That is the root cause of the problem. That is why there is a lack of training for you and a lack of proper documentation / hand-off of existing tickets.
Since you don't want to be a ticket-closing-drone, this means that you have to work around your boss. But, be smart about it. Everything you ask permission to do that isn't a direct close ticket must be in small amounts of time.
This will allow you to get more done by understanding the product better. It hopefully will help your career growth. That should get you more trust from the manager.
In time, perhaps you'll be the manager.

What makes you think that is how the priorities are being set? OP didn't say in their post that management is pushing for quantity over quality with tickets, just that communication with their coworkers is an obstacle for reaching their quotas.

@InBedded16  How 'bout the 2nd sentence?  "only metric he looks at is the number of cases I close per day in the ticket management system. He wants me to bring this number up."  That is why the other people don't give a crap about how they hand-off their tickets, just they get to show better through-put. You know - like a faster flushing toliet. The client doesn't count at this company. The OP still cares about doing a good job.

Just because management wants the ticket resolves to increase doesn't mean they're automatically crappy or short sighted. OP isn't short on tickets because they want to do a good job, they're short because they can't communicate well with their coworkers - even though none of their coworkers seem to have issues with that. More tickets solved wouldn't take a drop in quality, it would take learning how their coworkers communicate and doing a better job at that.

It is the manager's job to ensure proper training. Focusing on quantity of tickets before focusing on ability to communicate is a red flag for me. I have a similar problem with one of my managers. They are great at running their department. On boarding new team members has to be handled by other managers. They just can't wrap their head around what it is like to not know how to initially do the job anymore. We came up with a solution.

OP hasn't even brought up this issue to their managers yet. Sure you can argue that the manager should have tried to figure out why OP is struggling, but my point is its wrong to mischaracterize them the way that you did, talking about not prioritizing client satisfaction and wanting their employees to be "ticket closing drones". You have no idea if those things are true.
